# Is it possible to have a git configuration that depends on the installed version fo git

Tags: git, config

I have a global `.gitconfig` file where I defined as an alias

```
alias.tree=log --pretty="format:%C(auto)%h %ad%d [%aN, %G?] - %s %N" --all --decorate --graph --color --date=short
```

However, the default versions of git installed on most of my systems (Debian 7), is 1.7. I am generally happy with those. However that alias does not work as defined with that older version of git.

So, is there a way in `.gitconfig` to test the `git --version` and define the alias accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, or more precisely, not quite the way you're thinking.  What you *can* do is use a bit of shell script.  The clearest, albeit least efficient, way may be to write three aliases:

```
[alias]
    tree = "!f() { set -- $(git --version | \
            sed -e 's/git version //' -e 's/\\./ /g'); \
            if [ $1 -eq 1 -a $2 -le 7 ]; then git tree17 \"$@\"; \
            else git tree18plus \"$@\"; fi; }; f"
    tree17 = whatever you want here
    tree18plus = whatever you want here
```

The `tree` alias now invokes the brief shell script test: is this version 1.7 or earlier (counting 1.7.x as "1.7 or earlier"), or is this version 1.8 or later?  If 1.7 or earlier, run `git tree178`, otherwise run `git tree18plus`.  You can then have those aliases do whatever you like.

Of course, if you are going this far, you might as well just write a shell script named `git-tree` and put that in your `$PATH` (I would put it in my `$HOME/scripts` directory; this is where I keep scripts that are the same regardless of the OS and CPU, while `$HOME/bin.amd64`, `$HOME/bin.sparc`, etc contain OS and/or architecture dependent binaries).  The script can then read:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# test git version, are we less than or equal to $1.$2?
gitvers_le() {
    local maj=$1 min=$2
    set -- $(git --version | sed -e 's/git version /' -e 's/\./ /g')
    if [ $1 -lt $maj ]; then return 0; fi # e.g., 1.x < 2.*
    [ $1 -eq $maj -a $2 -le $min ]
}

if gitvers_le 1 7; then
    git ...
else
    git ...
fi
```

When you run `git tree` (or indeed anything starting with `git` that Git can't find in a standard place) and you have an executable spelled `git-tree` (or git-*whatever*) in your `$PATH`, Git will run that.  The "front end" `git` simply parses some universal options, like `-c` and `-C` and `--work-tree` and so on, and then invokes the "back end" *git-whatever* program to do the work, with these universal options handled somehow (usually by setting some environment variables).

---

Note that all these options switch at *runtime*, which is good if you have an admin constantly upgrading and/or downgrading your binaries underneath you.  Another method is to do your setup *once*, initially shuffling items around (e.g., renaming scripts in `$HOME/scripts`, or re-setting `.gitconfig` alias settings) as appropriate for whatever is installed right now, and then re-running the "check and shuffle" command—a separate script you write yourself that does whatever is needed—if and when your admin upgrades or downgrades your binaries.

That is, the "out of the box" configuration is "reconfigure and run".  The already-reconfigured configuration is "run".  If the configured run fails, you say to yourself: *Aha, my box has been changed on me, I need to explicitly reconfigure.*  If you re-install from scratch, you set yourself back into "out of the box" mode, where you automatically reconfigure and run.

This is more efficient (no constant runtime testing), but requires that you remember what to do to reconfigure when things do change.